# Is there anyway for netbean users get connected to clearcase remote client server?

Tags: version-control, netbeans, clearcase

Just want to ask can netbean IDE get connected to clearcase remote client server which eclipse users can install a CCRC plugin to talk to that server? Thanks

Comment: Did you try the Clearcase plugin?

Comment: @a_horse The ClearCase plugging is for working with the full ClearCase client, not with CCRC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any CCRC plugging for netbean IDE.

So unless you use the CCRC API to somehow integrate the basic features (checkout, checking, lshistory, lsvtree,...) there doesn't seem to be a netbean-ready solution.

Comment: Thanks for reply VonC. I cannot find any information regarding the netbean plugin either. You just confirm that. Thanks